Postgresql query takes 9 minutes to execute, how can we reduce time to 60 seconds?
Below is my Postgresql query that is taking 9 minutes to execute. Please help me reduce the execution time to 60 seconds, so my API does not throw a timeout error.
SELECT DISTINCT
    rdfg.form_group_id,
    rdfg.kind,
    rdfg.label,
    rdfg.tenant_id,
    rdfg.form_fields,
    rdfg.form_group_options,
    rpagp.group_path_resource_id,
    rpagp.path_resource_id,
    rpagp.group_path_id,
    rpagp.group_id,
    rpagp.path_id,
    rdg.end_state AS group_end_state,
    rdg.end_state_code AS group_end_state_code,
    rdg.group_end_date,
    rdpc.program_id,
    rdpc.cohort_id
FROM
    reporting_details_form_group rdfg
JOIN
    reporting_path_activity_group_paths rpagp 
  ON rpagp.group_path_resource_resourceable_type IN ('FormGroup',
  'CheckinTouchpoint', 'CheckinInterview', 'GenericFeedback::Template')
 AND rdfg.group_path_resource_ids && ARRAY[rpagp.group_path_resource_id]
LEFT JOIN
    reporting_details_groups rdg ON rpagp.group_id = rdg.group_id
LEFT JOIN
    reporting_details_programs_cohorts rdpc ON rdpc.group_id = rpagp.group_id;

Explain plan is https://explain.depesz.com/s/eFrN
This data required to be unique so distinct can't be removed

The plan linked only took 5 seconds, but doesn't seem to be for that query.

Storing IDs in an array instead of a child table is a design decision for conveniene against speed. In other words: It was decided that such queries take time.

Why SELECT DISTINCT? Why would there be duplicates in the result? SELECT DISTINCT is often an indicator for an badly designed data model or an inappropriate query (e.g., joins when it should be EXISTS or IN).

@jjanes I have updated new explain plan  link . Please find the link below https://explain.depesz.com/s/eFrN

The lion's share of your time comes from the sort step needed to satisfy DISTINCT in your query. There isn't much magic that speeds up sorting and emitting that many rows.

There's no WHERE clause in the query. That means it's reading the entire tables. Why are you expecting the query to be fast in the first place?

Increase your work_mem, to a few hundred MB or more. An index on group_path_resource_resourceable_type looks useful as well, most data is currently filtered out afterwards.

@TheImpaler The WHERE condition is hidden in the JOIN conditions. Since this an INNER JOIN, I would use a straight forward WHERE instead of the additional JOIN condition to avoid confusion like this.

Your sort is exorbitantly slow, for no good reason that I can see.  Could be an IO problem (turn on track_io_timing if not on already, then do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).  Could be a slow access to the system clock issue (do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, timing off) and see of the runtime is about the same as without timing off), could be very bad performance for your collation (what is the collation?).

@TheImpaler after changing the on condition to where clause its increate the query time from 9 minutes to 19 minutes
